# Cooking Porridge in steam oven

Tags: breakfast, oats

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to cook porridge in a steam oven?  We're not fond of porridge in the microwave, and, as we never have much time in the morning, we are not able to cook porridge on the stove and allow it to cool for our toddler. I was thinking of trying it in the steam oven with the timer to cook an hour or so before we get up.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what a steam oven is, but you can certainly cook porridge in a gas or electric oven. You can also pre-cook porridge the night before and rewarm it in the microwave.

Comment: @JenPen Microwave ovens make the best porridge, what is going wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a steam oven is either, but I think I can answer: YES!

I regularly cook porridge in an unsealed/unlocked pressure cooker that has been set on a hotplate which is plugged into an appliance timer.  I put my oats and liquid into a metal canister that fits inside my pressure cooker, and I put foil on top of the canister to keep extra water from dripping into it.  The pressure cooker has a "rack" in it to keep the canister off the bottom of the pot, which keeps the porridge from burning on the bottom, no matter how high you turn up the heat.

I keep the hotplate set to just barely a boil, because I use 100% milk for my liquid and don't want it to scald.

I have the timer set to start cooking it a full 3 or 4 hours before we wake up.  I prefer to soak my grains overnight, so I set everything up the night before, and we just wake up and eat!